# How to declare specialization template method outside class?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

The Converter class is designed to convert a string into another type. So if the target is also a string, then it should just return copy of the original value.

The working code is like this:

```
template<typename C>
class Converter {
public:
    template<typename T>
    static T To(const std::wstring& obj);

    template<>
    static std::wstring To(const std::wstring& obj) {
        return obj;
    }
};

template<typename C>
template<typename T>
T Converter<C>::To(const std::wstring& obj) {
    // Conversion
    return T();
}
```

(Works on VC++2015 Update 3)

I tried to move the specialization method outside the class declaration like this:

```
template<typename C>
template<>
std::wstring Converter<C>::To<std::wstring>(const std::wstring& obj) {
    return obj;
}
```

And there are several compilation errors:

> Error C3212   'Converter::To': an explicit specialization of a
>   template member must be a member of an explicit specialization
>
> Error C2768   'Converter::To': illegal use of explicit template
>   arguments

Comment: Your "working code" [doesn't even work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/852632a3c4a83d69).

Comment: I think both are actually illegal according to the standard, but for some reason MSVC allows the first anyway. Neither work under GCC. It looks like you can’t explicitly specialize an inner template without specializing the outer template.

Comment: @cdhowie works on VC++2015.

Comment: @cdhowie It’s tagged [visual-c++]. It works in Visual C++.

Comment: Side note: your second declaration in first example is **not** a specialization. Specialization would specify the parameter of the template: `To<std::wstring>`. I would say it is closer to being an overload if one could create a function template without any parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb:

> prefer function overload over specialization!

In your case use overload and sfinae:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename C>
class Converter {
public:
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, std::wstring>::value>::type* = nullptr >
    static T To(const std::wstring& obj) {

    }

    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::wstring>::value>::type* = nullptr >
    static std::wstring To(const std::wstring& obj) {

    }
};
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Rye7Ob4SmqtjbkIa)

Comment: Is there a way to declare those 2 methods out side the class declaration?

Comment: @user1633272 [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lxFUNqwda7AvIann) you go

Comment: @user1633272 can't you use `typename Converter<CharType>::StringType` inside `std::is_same`?

Comment: No, I can not use it, see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B8xK9gAWDhugCIEa), the code doesn't work on VC++2015. However I should be able to simplify the 2nd argument to std::basic_string<CharType>. Here's the [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bq3m4uxQKop1MY2Z).

Comment: The error message is: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration in VC2015.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is explicitly prohibited:

> **[temp.expl.spec]/16** In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, except that **the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well** [emphasis mine]... [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T1> class A {
>   template<class T2> class B {
>     template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
>     void mf2();
>   };
> };
> template <> template <class X>
>   class A<int>::B {
>     template <class T> void mf1(T);
>   };
> template <> template <> template<class T>
>   void A<int>::B<double>::mf1(T t) { }
>
> template <class Y> template <>
>   void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { } // ill-formed; B<double> is specialized but
>                                   // its enclosing class template A is not
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Answer (score 2):

You might use tag dispatching instead:

```
template <typename> struct Tag{};

template<typename C>
class Converter {

    template<typename T>
    static T To(const std::wstring& obj, Tag<T>);

    static std::wstring To(const std::wstring& obj, Tag<std::wstring>);

public:
    template<typename T>
    static T To(const std::wstring& obj) { return To(obj, Tag<T>{}); }
};
```

And then

```
template<typename C>
template<typename T>
T Converter<C>::To(const std::wstring& obj, Tag<T>) {
    // Conversion
    return T();
}

template<typename C>
std::wstring Converter<C>::To(const std::wstring& obj, Tag<std::wstring>) {
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported in c++, answer from Igor is correct. Still there is a trick.

But firstly - why it can be really needed?

In my case: lets say I want to "overload" function only by return type providing a template argument and I do not want do a mess in the header with large definitions.

That case differs from authors one but problem and solution are the same.

The trick is to make for each explicit template a correspondant method without template:

```
// SomeClass.h
template <typename ClassType>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    template <typename ReturnType> ReturnType Get(const std::string& parameter) const;

    template <>
    inline int Get<int>(const std::string& parameter) const { return GetInt(parameter); }

    template <>
    inline float Get<float>(const std::string& parameter) const { return GetFloat(parameter); }

    template <>
    inline std::string Get<std::string>(const std::string& parameter) const { return GetString(parameter); }

private:
    int GetInt(const std::string& parameter) const;
    float GetFloat(const std::string& parameter) const;
    std::string GetString(const std::string& parameter) const;
}


// SomeClass.inl
template <typename ClassType>
int SomeClass<ClassType>::GetInt(const std::string& parameter) const { ... }

template <typename ClassType>
float SomeClass<ClassType>::GetFloat(const std::string& parameter) const { ... }

template <typename ClassType>
std::string SomeClass<ClassType>::GetString(const std::string& parameter) const { ... }
```

As these methods are private you can give them whatever long trash names you want.

Now its usage will look like this:

```
SomeClass<WhateverType> a;

int count = a.Get<int>("count");
float width = a.Get<float>("width");
std::string name = a.Get<std::string>("name");
```